Control Python Library. Incorrect Impulse_response amplitude values
I am writing a system to evaluate the stability of frequency synthesis systems, I am trying to plot the impulse response, but for some reason the amplitude value exceeds the correct value by 5 * 10^6 times. For another method of calculating the transfer function by a factor of 2 * 10^10. Although the step response for these methods is output correctly.
Function for first method:
def calculate_params(Kvco, Ip, fc, pm, Fmax, Fref):
    N = Fmax * 1e3 / Fref  # c. units
    KvcoR = Kvco * 2 * np.pi * 1e6  # Rad/(V*s)
    IpA = Ip * 1e-6  # A
    fcHz = fc * 1e3  # Hz
    wc = fcHz * 2 * np.pi  # Rad/s
    pm_rad = (pm * np.pi) / 180  # Rad
    sec_pm_rad = 1 / np.cos(pm_rad)  # Rad
    tan_pm_rad = np.tan(pm_rad)  # Rad
    tp = (sec_pm_rad - tan_pm_rad) / wc  # s
    tz = 1 / (wc ** 2 * tp)  # s
    Kpd = IpA / (2 * np.pi)  # A/Rad
    C1 = (tp * Kpd * KvcoR / (tz * wc * wc * N) * np.sqrt((1 + wc * wc * tz * tz) / (1 + wc * wc * tp * tp)))  # Farad
    C2 = C1 * ((tz / tp) - 1)  # Farad
    R2 = tz / (C1 * ((tz / tp) - 1))  # Om

    num = [(Kpd * KvcoR * R2 * C2) / N, (Kpd * KvcoR) / N]
    den = [R2 * C1 * C2, C1 + C2, 0, 0]

    return num, den

Function for second:
def calc_params_2(Kvco, Icp, phi, Fref, N, ATTEN, Ft, C1, C2, C3, R2, R3):
    Kpd = Icp / (2 * np.pi)
    wt = (2 * np.pi) * Ft  # rad / s
    wref = (2 * np.pi) * Fref  # rad / s
    phi_rad = (phi * np.pi) / 180  # rad
    # phi_rad_sin = np.sin(phi_rad)  # rad
    # phi_rad_cos = np.cos(phi_rad)  # rad
    phi_rad_sec = 1 / np.cos(phi_rad)  # rad
    phi_rad_tan = np.tan(phi_rad)  # rad

    tp3_0 = np.sqrt((10 ** (ATTEN / 20) - 1) / (wref ** 2))
    tp1_0 = (phi_rad_sec - phi_rad_tan) / wt
    wc_0_o3t2 = wt
    wc_0_o3t3 = (phi_rad_tan * (tp1_0 + tp3_0) / ((tp1_0 + tp3_0) ** 2 + tp1_0 * tp3_0)) * (
            np.sqrt(1 + ((tp1_0 + tp3_0) ** 2 + tp1_0 * tp3_0) / (phi_rad_tan * (tp1_0 + tp3_0)) ** 2) - 1)
    tz1_1 = 1 / (wc_0_o3t3 ** 2 * (tp1_0 + tp3_0))
    tp3_0 = np.sqrt((10 ** (ATTEN / 20) - 1) / (wref ** 2))
    tz1_00 = 1 / (wc_0_o3t2 ** 2 * tp1_0)
    t1_o3t2 = tp1_0
    t2_o3t2 = tz1_00
    t1 = tp1_0  # s
    t2 = tz1_1  # s
    t3 = tp3_0  # s
    C1_eva = (t1 / t2) * ((Kpd * Kvco) / (wc_0_o3t3 ** 2 * N)) * np.sqrt(
        (1 + wc_0_o3t3 ** 2 * t2 ** 2) / ((1 + wc_0_o3t3 ** 2 * t1 ** 2) * (1 + wc_0_o3t3 ** 2 * t3 ** 2)))  # +++
    C2_eva = C1_eva * ((t2 / t1) - 1)
    R2_eva = t2 / (C1_eva * ((t2 / t1) - 1))  # Ohm
    # R2_eva_2 = t2 / C2_eva  # Ohm
    C3_eva = t3 / R3  # F
    R3_eva = R3  # Ohm

    C1_eva_o3t2 = t1_o3t2 * ((Kpd * Kvco) / (t2_o3t2 * wc_0_o3t2 ** 2 * N)) * np.sqrt(
        (1 + wc_0_o3t2 ** 2 * t2_o3t2 ** 2) / (1 + wc_0_o3t2 ** 2 * t1_o3t2 ** 2))  # +++
    C2_eva_o3t2 = C1_eva_o3t2 * ((t2_o3t2 / t1_o3t2) - 1)  # F + ++
    R2_eva_o3t2 = t2_o3t2 / (C1_eva_o3t2 * ((t2_o3t2 / t1_o3t2) - 1))  # Ohm + ++

    # FLF_second_B = [R2_eva_o3t2 * C2_eva_o3t2, 1]  # numerator
    # FLF_second_A = [C1_eva_o3t2 * C2_eva_o3t2 * R2_eva_o3t2, C1_eva_o3t2 + C2_eva_o3t2, 0]  # denumerator
    # FLF_second_F = tf(FLF_second_B, FLF_second_A)  # eva transfer func
    #
    # FLF_second_B_man = [R2 * C2, 1]  # numerator
    # FLF_second_A_man = [C1 * C2 * R2, C1 + C2, 0]  # denumerator
    # FLF_second_F_man = tf(FLF_second_B_man, FLF_second_A_man)  # man transfer func

    FLF_third_B = [R2_eva * C2_eva * R3_eva * C3_eva, (R3_eva * C3_eva + R2_eva * C2_eva), 1]
    FLF_third_A = [C1_eva * R2_eva * C2_eva * R3_eva * C3_eva, (C1_eva + C2_eva) * R3_eva
                   * C3_eva + R2_eva * C2_eva * (C1_eva + C3_eva), C1_eva + C2_eva + C3_eva, 0]
    # FLF_third_F = tf(FLF_third_B, FLF_third_A)

    FLF_third_B_man = [R2 * C2 * R3 * C3, (R3 * C3 + R2 * C2), 1]
    FLF_third_A_man = [C1 * R2 * C2 * R3 * C3, (C1 + C2) * R3 * C3 + R2 * C2 * (C1 + C3), C1 + C2 + C3, 0]
    # FLF_third_F_man = tf(FLF_third_B_man, FLF_third_A_man)

    return FLF_third_B, FLF_third_A, FLF_third_B_man, FLF_third_A_man

Body of impulse response plot:
     def plot_impulse(self):
        if self.method_check.isChecked():
            Kvco = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'Kvco'))  # MHz/V
            Ip = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'Ip'))  # uA
            fc = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'fc'))  # kHz
            pm = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'pm'))  # degree
            Fmax = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'Fmax'))  # MHz
            Fref = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS', 'Fref'))  # kHz
            num, den = calculate_params(Kvco, Ip, fc, pm, Fmax, Fref)
        elif self.method_check2.isChecked():
            Kvco = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'Kvco')) * 1e+06 * (2 * np.pi)  #
            Icp = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'Icp')) * 1e-06  #
            phi = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'phi'))  #
            Fref = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'fref')) * 1e+06  #
            Fmax = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'fmax')) * 1e+06  #
            N = Fmax / Fref  #
            ATTEN = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'atten'))  #
            Ft = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'ft')) * 1e+03  #
            C1 = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'c1')) * 1e-12  #
            R2 = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'r2')) * 1e+03  #
            C2 = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'c2')) * 1e-12  #
            R3 = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'r3')) * 1e+03  #
            C3 = float(self.config.get('IP_PARAMS2', 'c3')) * 1e-12  #
            num, den, _, _ = calc_params_2(Kvco, Icp, phi, Fref, N, ATTEN, Ft, C1, C2, C3, R2, R3)

        w = tf(num, den)
        lf = feedback(w)
        y, x = impulse(lf)
        y3 = list(y)
        x3 = list(x)
        y_max = y3.index(max(y3))
        y_MAX = max(y3)
        x_yMax = x3[y_max]
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y, "r")
        plt.plot(x_yMax, y_MAX, 'ob', label=f'Peak:\n[{x_yMax:.2e}; {y_MAX:.2f}]')
        plt.title('Impulse Response ')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.xlabel('Time(sec)')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.legend()
        return plt.show()

First method tf calc
Second method tf calc
I tried to find errors in the calculation of transfer functions, but I did not find any differences from the methodology.
